# Array Push with associative to array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$row_properties = array(
                         "Header 11"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255),"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)),
                         "Header 12"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255),"text_color"=>array(220,50,50) )
```

);

How I can Push the values

```
"Header 13"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255) ,"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)),
"Header 14"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255) ,"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)),
```

SO it will got the result

```
$row_properties = array(
"Header  11"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255),"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)),
"Header12"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255),"text_color"=>array(220,50,50),
"Header 13"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255) ,"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)),
"Header 14"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255) ,"text_color"=>array(220,50,50))
                  )
              );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
$row_properties["Header 13"] = array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255) ,"text_color"=>array(220,50,50));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried the `array_merge()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$push_vals = array(
    "Header 13"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255) ,"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)),
    "Header 14"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255) ,"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)),
);

$arr = array(
     "Header 11"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255),"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)),
     "Header 12"=>array("width"=>20,"align"=>'C',"color"=>array(100,220,255),"text_color"=>array(220,50,50)
);

foreach ($push_vals as $key=>$value){
    if ( isset($arr[$key]) ) 
        $arr = array_merge($arr[$key], $push_vals[$key]);
    else
        $arr[$key] = $push_vals[$key];

}
```

### Update

durrr [array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)